# SqlDataSource - want to trace the data returned

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, sqldatasource, trace, diagnostics

I am using the `SqlDataSource` object in my `ASP.NET` application.

However, one of the things I would like to do is to always capture pertinent information in my trace, so:

1. the SQL command sent to the database
2. the results returned from the database.

My approach was therefore to create my own "`MySqlDataSource`" object which inherits from the `SqlDataSource`.

I handle the events `(inserted, updated, selected, deleted`) and can easily grab the SqlCommand object and therefore trace the data that's sent to the database.

What I've not worked out yet is how to intercept the results (I guess this is a datatable?) - I only want to trace the first row of data returned.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Griff

Answer (score 0):

> What I've not worked out yet is how to intercept the results (I guess
>   this is a datatable?) - I only want to trace the first row of data
>   returned.

There's no way to trace only the first row of data returned unless you put code in there that specifically logs/traces the first row returned and let the process continue its marry way.

Comment: Yup - I will write the code to trace just the first row, that's not the problem. What I need to know is which method/property on the SqlDataSource exposes the actual result used for DataBinding.  Once I know that, I'll override that method/property and "intercept" the data in there.

Comment: @drgriff sorry, I misinterpreted your question. You can call SqlDatasource.Select method, which returns a DataView from which you can select the first row or even call DataView.ToDatabTable();

Comment: The Select method is not marked as virtual, so it appears that I can't override it directly.  I tried to "hide" it by creating a NEW method in the "MySqlDataSource" class with the signature: public new IEnumerable Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) { return base.Select(arguments); }, but this method is never called (and the data is displayed in my grids, so I'm guessing that the original method in the base class is still being called.  Any ideas?